# Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'No database provider has been configured for this DbContext

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have problem that I can't solve on my own, so I'm asking for help.

I want to build a library where I have to have a database, login system and administrator powers to be able to add and delete books from the website but this error pops up:

> Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'No database
> provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be
> configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by
> using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If
> 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type
> accepts a DbContextOptions<TContext> object in its constructor and
> passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.' was thrown while
> attempting to create an instance.

This is my code:

AppDbContext.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MoviePage.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MoviePage.Data
{
public partial class AppDbContext:DbContext
{
public AppDbContext() { }
public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions\<AppDbContext\> options) :
base(options)
{
}

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Actor_Movie>().HasKey(am => new
            {
                am.ActorId,
                am.MovieId
            });
    
            modelBuilder.Entity<Actor_Movie>().HasOne(m => m.Movie).WithMany(am => am.Actors_Movies).HasForeignKey(m =>
                m.MovieId);
    
            modelBuilder.Entity<Actor_Movie>().HasOne(m => m.Actor).WithMany(am => am.Actors_Movies).HasForeignKey(m =>
                m.ActorId);
    
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
}
}
```

Startup.cs

```cs
using MoviePage.Data;
using MoviePage.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MoviePage
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            //DbContext configuration
            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnectionString")));

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
             
            // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        }


    }
}
```

I'm learning ASP.Net so sorry if I just have like a dumb error

Comment: what does your connection string look like?

Comment: If you talk about my the connection strings on Appsettings.json, it looks like this:



`
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },

  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnectionString": "Data Source=DESKTOP-H67N688\\KARLSEFNI;Initial Catalog=streaming-app-dbase;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;Encrypt=False;Trust Server Certificate=True"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
`

Comment: Also, it's strange that you're using a partial class for your AppDbContext

Comment: Yes, i was trying a lot of things i just change that. Sorry if I'm commenting a bit disorganized, it's my first time posting here

Comment: Try changing your implementation to a non-partial class: public class AppDbContext:DbContext

Comment: Also, does your database already exist? If not, look into seeding and database creation with code first.

Comment: i already did the connection and i see the database on my Sql Server

Comment: When is the error raised?

Comment: Remove the empty constructor?

Comment: Chances are your code is trying to new up a new DbContext using the default constructor, removing that default constructor will confirm any code trying to use it. The services.AddDbContext is setting up for dependency injection so if you have a Controller that you want a DbContext available, create a private, read-only member and accept the DbContext via the constructor. This should ensure that the initialized DbContext instance with SQL Server options set up is injected.

Comment: Ensure that the NuGet package for SQL Server, `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`, is installed in your project. This package is required to use SQL Server as the database provider with Entity Framework Core. Then consider adding debug logging to check whether the configuration values, especially the connection string, are being loaded as expected.  `var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnectionString");
    Console.WriteLine($"Connection String: {connectionString}");` in Startup.cs.

Comment: Can you share your models?